# Adding numbers every alternate 2 lines using awk

Tags: awk

I need to add numbers and print sum every alternate 2 lines.

ex:

```
x  
1  
2  
y  
3  
4
```

i need output :

```
x 3  
y 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using the [`pr` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html) and Awk.

Using the following input:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
x  
1  
2  
y  
3  
4
```

First convert input file to three column input, and then use Awk:

```
$ pr -3at ip.txt | awk '{print $1, $2+$3}'
x 3
y 7
```

---

Another way with [`getline` `<var>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable.html#Getline_002fVariable):

> The getline command used in this way sets only the variables NR, FNR,
>   and RT (and, of course, var). The record is not split into fields, so
>   the values of the fields (including $0) and the value of NF do not
>   change.

```
$ awk '{getline a; getline b; print $0 a+b}' ip.txt 
x  3
y  7
```

Comment: Very nice.  You could simplify the first Awk solution to `pr -3at ip.txt | awk '{print $1, $2+$3}'`.

Comment: @Wildcard thanks, that is simpler and trick to keep in mind for later

Comment: @Sundeep  ,  getline command is also very useful ... thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, making use of awk's `getline` statement.

```
$ awk '{a=$0;getline;b=$1;getline;print a,b+$1}' ip.txt
x 3
y 7
$
```

Comment: getline command is very useful !!! thank you